# Java Do-While Loop - How to End the Program Using Q Option

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, do-while

so i have this simple bank program. it has main menus which are:

- B - Check for Balance
- D - Make Deposit
- W - Make Withdraw
- Q - Quit

their functions are basically their names. and there are two ways to terminate the program: by inputting 'Q' and 'N'.but I have a problem with the Q - Quit option. here's the source code:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        
    char anotherTransact = 0, option;
    int balance = 100000, deposit = 0, withdraw = 0;
    
    do {
    System.out.println("\nWelcome to ABC BANK \n");
    
    System.out.println("B - Check for Balance");
    System.out.println("D - Make Deposit");
    System.out.println("W - Make Withdraw");
    System.out.println("Q - Quit");
    
    
        System.out.print("\nSelect an option : ");
        option = scan.next().charAt(0);
        
        
        if ((option == 'B') || (option == 'b')) {
            System.out.println("\nYour current balance is " +balance);
        }
        
        else if ((option == 'D') || (option == 'd')) {
            System.out.print("\nEnter amount to Deposit : ");
            deposit = scan.nextInt();
            if (deposit > 1 && deposit <= 500000) {
                System.out.println("Deposit Transaction is successfully completed.");
                balance = balance + deposit; 
            }
            else if (deposit > 500000) {
                System.out.println("Deposit Amount must not be greater than 500,000");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Deposit must be greater than zero");
            }
        }
        
        else if ((option == 'W') || (option == 'w')) {
            System.out.print("\nEnter amount to Withdraw : ");
            withdraw = scan.nextInt();
            if ((withdraw % 100 == 0 && withdraw < 150000)) {
                System.out.println("Withdrawal Transaction is successfully completed.");
                balance = balance - withdraw;
            }
            else if (withdraw > 150000) {
                System.out.println("Withdrawal Amount must not be greater then 150,000");
            }
            else if (withdraw < 0) {
                System.out.println("Withdrawal Amount must be greater than zero");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Withdawal Amount must be divisible by 100");
            }
        }
        
        else if ((option == 'Q') || (option == 'q')) 
            break;
        
        else {
            System.out.println("\nInvalid entry, enter any valid option : (B/D/W/Q)");
        }
        
        
        System.out.print("\nWant to Transact another (Y/N?) ");
        anotherTransact = scan.next().charAt(0);
        
        System.out.println("\n======================================================"); 
    }
    
    
    while ((anotherTransact == 'Y') || (anotherTransact =='y'));
        if ((anotherTransact == 'N' || anotherTransact == 'n')) {
            System.out.println("\nThank you for using this program!");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid entry, entery any valid option : (Y/N)");
        }
    scan.close();
```

and its output would be like this:

```
Welcome to ABC BANK 

B - Check for Balance
D - Make Deposit
W - Make Withdraw
Q - Quit

Select an option :
```

The output should be like this when i input the Q option:

```
Welcome to ABC BANK 

B - Check for Balance
D - Make Deposit
W - Make Withdraw
Q - Quit

Select an option : Q
======================================================

Thank you for using this program!
```

but when i input it, it would say that it is an invalid input. what should i do to end the program by inputting 'Q'?

Comment: `(anotherTransact == 'N' || anotherTransact == 'n')` extend this with `anotherTransact == 'Q'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

1. **Putting the following code outside the scope of `do-while` loop:**

   ```
   if ((anotherTransact == 'N' || anotherTransact == 'n')) {
       System.out.println("\nThank you for using this program!");
   } else {
       System.out.println("Invalid entry, entery any valid option : (Y/N)");
   }
   ```

   However, just correcting this problem is not sufficient. Check the next point/problem to understand what needs to be done in order to get it working as per your expectation.
2. **Not looping back in case of invalid input:** You need another loop (I recommend `do-while` loop as shown below) to rectify this problem.

   ```
   boolean valid;
   do {
       valid = true;
       System.out.print("\nWant to Transact another (Y/N?) ");
       anotherTransact = scan.next().charAt(0);

       System.out.println("\n======================================================");

       if (anotherTransact == 'N' || anotherTransact == 'n') {
           System.out.println("\nThank you for using this program!");
       } else if (!(anotherTransact == 'Y' || anotherTransact == 'y')) {
           System.out.println("Invalid entry, entery any valid option : (Y/N)");
           valid = false;
       }
   } while (!valid);
   ```

**The full updated code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        char anotherTransact = 0, option;
        int balance = 100000, deposit = 0, withdraw = 0;
        do {
            System.out.println("\nWelcome to ABC BANK \n");

            System.out.println("B - Check for Balance");
            System.out.println("D - Make Deposit");
            System.out.println("W - Make Withdraw");
            System.out.println("Q - Quit");

            System.out.print("\nSelect an option : ");
            option = scan.next().charAt(0);

            if ((option == 'B') || (option == 'b')) {
                System.out.println("\nYour current balance is " + balance);
            } else if ((option == 'D') || (option == 'd')) {
                System.out.print("\nEnter amount to Deposit : ");
                deposit = scan.nextInt();
                if (deposit > 1 && deposit <= 500000) {
                    System.out.println("Deposit Transaction is successfully completed.");
                    balance = balance + deposit;
                } else if (deposit > 500000) {
                    System.out.println("Deposit Amount must not be greater than 500,000");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Deposit must be greater than zero");
                }
            } else if ((option == 'W') || (option == 'w')) {
                System.out.print("\nEnter amount to Withdraw : ");
                withdraw = scan.nextInt();
                if ((withdraw % 100 == 0 && withdraw < 150000)) {
                    System.out.println("Withdrawal Transaction is successfully completed.");
                    balance = balance - withdraw;
                } else if (withdraw > 150000) {
                    System.out.println("Withdrawal Amount must not be greater then 150,000");
                } else if (withdraw < 0) {
                    System.out.println("Withdrawal Amount must be greater than zero");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Withdawal Amount must be divisible by 100");
                }
            } else if ((option == 'Q') || (option == 'q')) {
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("\nInvalid entry, enter any valid option : (B/D/W/Q)");
            }

            boolean valid;
            do {
                valid = true;
                System.out.print("\nWant to Transact another (Y/N?) ");
                anotherTransact = scan.next().charAt(0);

                System.out.println("\n======================================================");

                if (anotherTransact == 'N' || anotherTransact == 'n') {
                    System.out.println("\nThank you for using this program!");
                } else if (!(anotherTransact == 'Y' || anotherTransact == 'y')) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid entry, entery any valid option : (Y/N)");
                    valid = false;
                }
            } while (!valid);
        } while (anotherTransact == 'Y' || anotherTransact == 'y');
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Welcome to ABC BANK 

B - Check for Balance
D - Make Deposit
W - Make Withdraw
Q - Quit

Select an option : b

Your current balance is 100000

Want to Transact another (Y/N?) d

======================================================
Invalid entry, entery any valid option : (Y/N)

Want to Transact another (Y/N?) d

======================================================
Invalid entry, entery any valid option : (Y/N)

Want to Transact another (Y/N?) y

======================================================

Welcome to ABC BANK 

B - Check for Balance
D - Make Deposit
W - Make Withdraw
Q - Quit

Select an option : d

Enter amount to Deposit : 200
Deposit Transaction is successfully completed.

Want to Transact another (Y/N?) y

======================================================

Welcome to ABC BANK 

B - Check for Balance
D - Make Deposit
W - Make Withdraw
Q - Quit

Select an option : b

Your current balance is 100200

Want to Transact another (Y/N?) n

======================================================

Thank you for using this program!
```

**Some additional side notes:**

1. You should **never close** the `Scanner` for `System.in` as it will also close `System.in` and there is no way to open it again without restarting the JVM. However, make sure to close a `Scanner` for a file.
2. You should make a habit of enclosing the body of a block within `{...}` even if you have a single statement in the body. This will save you from some statement accidentally falling out of scope e.g.

   ```
   if (1 == 2)
       System.out.print("Hello");
       System.out.println("World");

   System.out.println("What's up?");
   ```

will print

```
World
What's up?
```

and not just

```
What's up?
```

3. Keep your code well-formatted because it will help you find the problem easily and quickly. Your IDE can format the code on click of a button or when you press a combination of keys.

Answer (score 2):

Your Q implementation is correct, it will exit the do while loop, but after the while statement you have an if:

```java
 if ((anotherTransact == 'N' || anotherTransact == 'n')) {
            System.out.println("\nThank you for using this program!");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid entry, entery any valid option : (Y/N)");
        }
```

When you type Q to exit the loop `anotherTransact` is not equals to 'N' therefore it will go into the else and print invalid entry. If I understand correctly you dont actually need after the while statement is:

```
 System.out.println("\n======================================================"); 
 System.out.println("\nThank you for using this program!");
```